# Do you know a jQuery plugin for video file upload?

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I need a jQuery plugin for uploading video files. it should generate some pictures out of movie as it is uploading ( not after the file uploaded ). Do you know such a plugin? if there is no plugin with this feature, can you suggest me some tutorials or articles about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (as of this answer) do this in JavaScript, it's forbidden from touching the file like this (for hopefully obvious security reasons).  You can find a flash based solution, *maybe*, but video editing is still a very intensive thing.  For thumbnails, you're best off doing this server-side.

Your comment dismisses this because it's "time and resource consuming"...trust me, you doing this server-side correctly and returning a few KB in thumbnails is *far* faster than flash opening and playing with a video to get thumbnails (then uploading those too).  Also consider it from a security standpoint, it's consistent and prevents your uploader from sending fake thumbnails that don't match the video at all.

Comment: Thank you. you are right. If one select thumbnails in client side, they should be uploaded too. and it is not a good idea. you know, I want the user to have ability to complete information about movie without waiting for its upload to be completed. and one of the form's field is thumbnail selection.Maybe I do it just like youtube.

Answer (score 0):

In My Opinion you cannot find a uploading plugins based on its extension. Like Document uploader, Image uploader, video uploader, game uploader, sql uploader. This is not a genuine question, instead you can a uploader script to upload all these. And what you decide to do, or how you decide to present the uploaded file, its up to you.

Here is a plugin, for all in one purpose

Uploadify

http://www.uploadify.com/

However here are some links which can help

http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/

http://forum.coppermine-gallery.net/index.php?topic=38774.0

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/1371.htm

Comment: Thank you. but I don't want to upload file completely and then retrieving images from server. it is time and resource consuming. I need something like flickr uploader but for videos.